# Detect Existing Download in MVC c# for an application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I have an MVC application that has an action that serves file. I have a requirement that if a user has initiated a download, the user cannot initiate a new download until the current one finishes.

To put simply the user can only download one file at a time. However, I don't want to simply block the user's request but want to be able to let them know that they cannot download a new one because they are downloading an existing one.

So my question is how do you keep track when a download has been started and have not yet finished? I initially turned to dynamic ip restriction in IIS but the problem is the end user could be sitting behind layers upon layers of proxies which might not make it reliable. Is there a way to do this through code?

I also tried using FileWebRequest / FileWebResponse which creates an ongoing stream. But when a new request comes in it enters as a new action and I don't know how to check if the previous stream is still in progress.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Download()
    {
        Session["IsDownloading"]  = true;            
        await ServeFiles();
        return View("Index");
    }

public ActionResult CheckStatus()
    {
        var message = Session["IsDownloading"] ?? "Null";
        return Content(message.ToString());
    }
private async Task ServeFiles()
{
   try
   {    //Download async
   }
   finaly
   {
      Session["IsDownloading"] = false;
   }
}
```

***********************Update*********************

I've updated the sample code. **Download** can be invoked any number of time to download a file in c:\temp, then while that's downloading, I was trying to invoke **CheckStatus** but it doesn't respond while the download is in progress. Only when the download completes.

I've added a project solution here.
https://github.com/janmchan/DownloadThrottling.git

***********************Update 2016-04-04 **********

After a bit of search I found out that session (I'm using SQLServer) is saved at the end of the request so even if the user manages two concurrent request, the session variable won't be updated until the end of the request making the information in the session not reliable. So now, I'm looking for a way to manually force the session state to save right after I update the value.

Comment: Session will not work for you, since a session is browser specific (ie it's cookie based, and each browser handles cookies differently).  So (as I mention elsewhere) all you have to do is open a different browser to bypass any session security.  However, if you want to use session, you need only set the session flag, then redirect the browser to the file to download, this will insure the session variable is updated before the download begins.

Comment: You would also want to combine this with a unique download id that is generated on the fly to refer to a specific file, then when the download begins you mark it in the database as downloaded for that id and prevent it from being used again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution that I end up using is similar to @eugen's answer but instead of session, using data cache (MemoryCache) which immediately takes effect and does not wait for the request to finish. Although this is only in process, this is fine since I found out that even though the application servers will be load balanced, once a session is established, it is guaranteed by the client infrastructure that they will use the same set of server for the rest of the session.

I agree with Erik Funkenbusch's comment that the user can get easily get around this and this solution is only for this specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 things: identify a user, check+block if he has existing download.

The easiest way would be to set Session["isDownloading"]  = true; and then check this. Set it on false when he finished downloading.

From the client when he wants to initiate download you can use javascript to call a CheckIsDownloading action and if ok call Serve to get the file.

In serve check again and block if he is downloading to avoid scenarios where he hacks the js and makes download requests.

Note: the user identity part is hard to do if he isn't logged in and you want to make sure it's only one download. He could delete cookies at any time(->new session) and do a new download.

Comment: I tried this out but can't seem to get it to work properly. So I added a Session["IsDownloading"] = true at the start of Serve Action and after downloading it updates to false. Then I created another action CheckStatus which just reads the session, however, it seems blocked and does not respond until the download finished

Comment: not sure what you mean by blocked, you debuged this and and it stays on the line where you read from session? that would be strange. maybe you can update you question with implementation both client and server, no need to include actual file read code

Comment: Updated question and code. If you try to download (Download1/2) and click on check status, it doesn't respond until the download is complete.

Comment: @Eugen - even if the asker could figure out how to make this work, it's trivial to bypass, just open a different browser (firefox instead of chrome) and you would have a totally different session.